# I can't stream mp3 files from my server on Chrome

Tags: html, wordpress, mime-types, audio-streaming

I'm making an audio player on my website (which is powered through Wordpress) using jPlayer, but I can't get it to work in Chrome. I just found out that if I try to stream an mp3 player from my servers on Chrome, it won't even stream. Does anyone know why this might not work? Is there a way to force it to be able to stream so that I can get my jPlayer to work?

Try an example. Go to this page in both Firefox and in Chrome. It should stream fine on Firefox, and not play in Chrome. http://www.startingtofeelit.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/araabMUZIK-The-Prince-Is-Coming.mp3

I thought it might have to do with the MIME types. I'm not too familiar with these, but I opened my .htaccess file in the root folder of my server and added AddType audio/mpeg mp3 to the bottom, but this didn't seem to help either.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and it's streaming fine for me.

Comment: Weird... it's streaming okay for me now too but it wasn't before. I emptied my cache and now it seems to work. Interesting...

Comment: Interesting indeed. Time2Close this question.

Comment: I just went to my main page (http://www.startingtofeelit.com) and tried to stream it again, and now it doesn't work. Something must be loading from the servers that is blocking it. What's even stranger is if you close the tab that has the main page on it, the song will start playing/streaming again without you even having to try to refresh it.

Problem is not solved.

Comment: You could do to optimize your site a bit. Takes a good 10-20 seconds to load.

Comment: Yes I know. That's what I will work on after I get this to work. I think some of my pictures are too high a resolution, but that doesn't help with my problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since the stream can be played just fine, and you say you have very large images and when you close the page tab it works, I suspect that you are running into the concurrent connection limit.

Browsers will typically only make 3 or 4 requests to a server at a time.  If those connections are used up, it is unlikely the browser will make an additional request for the MP3 stream until those connections are done.  Ensure that you are using `keep-alive`, and optimize your site.